# Where to find logs within Spark RDD processing function ? (YARN CLUSTER MODE)

Tags: logging, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, spark-streaming

I am running my Spark Application on Yarn Cluster. No matter what I do, I am not able to get the logs within the RDD function printed . Below you can find the  sample snippet  which I have written for the RDD processing function .  I have simplified the code to illustrate the syntax I have used to write the function. When I am running it locally I am able to see the logs but not in cluster mode. Neither System.err.println nor the logger seems to be working. But I could see all my driver logs. I even tried to log using the Root logger , but it was not working at all within the RDD processing function .I was desperate to see the log messages so finally I found a guide to use logger as transient (https://www.mapr.com/blog/how-log-apache-spark) ,but event that didn't help

```
class SampleFlatMapFunction implements PairFlatMapFunction <Tuple2<String,String>,String,String>{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6565656322667L;
    transient Logger  executorLogger = LogManager.getLogger("sparkExecutor");


    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream in)
            throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
            in.defaultReadObject();
            executorLogger = LogManager.getLogger("sparkExecutor");
    }
    @Override
    public Iterable<Tuple2<String,String>> call(Tuple2<String, String> tuple)        throws Exception {

        executorLogger.info(" log testing from  executorLogger ::");
        System.err.println(" log testing from  executorLogger system error stream ");


            List<Tuple2<String, String>> updates = new ArrayList<>();
            //process Tuple , expand and add it to list.
            return updates;

         }
 };
```

My Log4j Configuration is given below

```
    log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
    log4j.appender.console.target=System.err
    log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{1}: %m%n

    log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
    log4j.appender.stdout.target=System.out
    log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{1}: %m%n

    log4j.appender.RollingAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
    log4j.appender.RollingAppender.File=/var/log/spark/spark.log
    log4j.appender.RollingAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
    log4j.appender.RollingAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.RollingAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p] %d %c %M - %m%n

    log4j.appender.RollingAppenderU=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
    log4j.appender.RollingAppenderU.File=${spark.yarn.app.container.log.dir}/spark-app.log
    log4j.appender.RollingAppenderU.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
    log4j.appender.RollingAppenderU.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.RollingAppenderU.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p] %d %c %M - %m%n


    # By default, everything goes to console and file
    log4j.rootLogger=INFO, RollingAppender, console

    # My custom logging goes to another file
    log4j.logger.sparkExecutor=INFO, stdout, RollingAppenderU
```

i have tried  yarn  logs, Spark UI Logs nowhere I could see the log statements from RDD processing functions . I tried below Approaches but it didn't work

```
yarn logs -applicationId 

I checked even below HDFS path also

/tmp/logs/
```

I am running my spark-submit command by passing below arguments, Even then its not working

```
  --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster   --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.properties"  --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.properties"
```

Can somebody guide me on logging within spark RDD and map functions ? What am I missing in the above steps ?

Comment: are you getting any output for  "yarn logs -applicationId <yarn applicationId> " command, ideally it should work

Comment: @shekhar , Yes I am getting output for  "yarn logs -applicationId <yarn applicationId> "  But it only contains Driver Logs , it doesn't contains logs from the RDD Processing function

Comment: check if log4j.properties exists on executor node, also specify complete path of log4j.properties file.

Comment: @shekhar, yes the log4j.properties exists at executor node and infact its even creating the RollingAppender file on the executor node. Also RollingAppenderU file is also getting created and I am able to see it on the hadoop UI under application log section. What I am not able to see the RDD log statements within those file.

Comment: @Ajay Have you solve this issue, I'm facing a similar problem, I would like to see the log messages inside the map loop of the RDD.

Comment: Any solution , I am trying to capture the driver log /streamed data to unix file location . But unable to do